# Configure path mapping for Magento 2 xdebug in phpstorm

Tags: magento2, phpstorm, xdebug

I have xdebug set up in phpstorm. However every time I load my Magento 2 app the script get.php opens 3 times in the debugger and breaks. I also get the error

"The script '/pub/get.php' is outside the project.
Click to set up path mappings."

My files are on the localhost, using MAMP.
I'm just starting with xdebug, and can't get this configured.

Answer (score 0):

Please reset all phpstrom's xdebug setting and follow these steps: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html#integrationWithProduct from the official documentation.

Settings/Preferences dialog Ctrl+Alt+S, select Languages & Frameworks | PHP.| Servers unselect Use path mappings for localhost.
Xdebug’s default debugging port has changed from 9000 to 9003 in xdebug3.
please consider that as well.